# Templates in c++,typename and class

Tags: c++, templates

What is the difference between writing a template in c++ in the below both ways

`template<typename T>`  &  `template<class T>`

and when do we prefer them above each other?
If both are same,then why do we have them both if one is enough?

Comment: I prefer `typename` because my templates accept non-class types (but yes, they are exactly equivalent of course)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No difference at all. I prefer first one (mostly), but that is my personal taste. The language doesn't make any difference between them.

For template parameters, the keywords `typename` and `class` are equivalent. §14.1.2 says:

> There is no semantic difference
>   between class and typename in a
>   template-parameter.

---

> If both are same,then why do we have them both if one is enough?

Stan Lippman explains this in his article:

[Why C++ Supports both Class and Typename for Type Parameters?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slippman/archive/2004/08/11/212768.aspx)

Comment: More information can be found [in this blogpost](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slippman/archive/2004/08/11/212768.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

These keywords are there because of historical reason. There's no difference between them. Read this:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slippman/archive/2004/08/11/212768.aspx