# Why can't you define a template with a struct?

Tags: c++, templates

Pretty straight-forward:

```
template <class T>
void foo() {}  //compiles

template <struct T>
void goo() {}  //doesn't
```

Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`class` is only a keyword to indicate that `T` is a type. It does not actually mean `T` must be a class. (e.g. you can call `foo<int>()`.)

The `class` keyword was used because `typename` didn't exist when the template feature was added. See [Templates in c++,typename and class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777137/templates-in-c-typename-and-class).

Comment: Ah. So you're saying class and typename are interchangeable with no side-effects whatsoever? +1 from me.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Almost. You have to use `class` in a template-template parameter `template <template <typename> class X>`, but then a struct-template can also be substituted into `X`.

Comment: `<template <typename> class X>` you lost me there.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Well if you don't know what it is, then yes `class` and `typename` are interchangeable inside the `<...>` ;). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6485439/224671 for an explanation of template-template parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Because a template has to be declared with either `class` or...

```
template <typename T>
void foo() {}
```

Comment: I'm looking more for the reasoning behind this specification, rather than just "because that's what the standard says".

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: There is not much to reason about... there is a need for a keyword that identifies a placeholder for a *type*, and while defining the language they could have decided basically *anything*, for example `template <type T>`, but they chose to use `class` (reuse of an existing keyword to avoid incrementing the number of reserved keywords). Note that this use of `class` is not synonym for `class` in a type declaration, which is the use of `class` that is in turn similar to `struct`.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas  Actually Kenny's answer provides a pretty good explanation. Even your comment provides more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Because, the grammar forbids it:

```
template-declaration: 

export_opt template< template-parameter-list > declaration

template-parameter-list:
template-parameter
parameter-declaration

type-parameter:

class identifier
class identifier = type-id
typename identifier
typename identifier = type-id
template < template-parameter-list > class identifier
template < template-parameter-list > class identifier = template-name
```

Alternatively , you can think that struct is a special case of a class where the members are all public. Thus, allowing it in the template-parameter-list would not be as general.